# Perl grep always returns number of matches even in list context

Tags: perl, list, grep

I have a script with the lists

```
@names = ();
@x = ();
```

Both lists are filled in parallel with data, therefore, in the end I have two lists with name and x-value for each element at the same index. Note, there are more than one element having the same x-value.

I want to have all elements having a specific x-value with the code

```
foreach my $x (0..4) {      
    my @ind = grep { $x[$_] == $x } 0..$#names;
    print @ind . "\n";
}
```

However, the output is

```
17
17
8
4
```

which is exactly the number of elements having x=0, x=1, ...

I'm wondering since grep in a list context should return me a list with the matches (here, the indizes of matching elements).

What am I doing wrong here?

Best regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
print @ind . "\n";
```

When you use the concatenation operator `.` you put both parameters into scalar context, and in scalar context, an array returns its size, not its content.

What you want is to use the comma operator instead:

```
print @ind , "\n";
```

Or better yet, use the feature `say`:

```
say @ind;
```

In case what you actually want is to print the numbers in a line, separated by space:

```
say "@ind";
```

Or in case you want to print them separated by newlines:

```
say for @ind;
```

In all the above, `say` can of course be replaced by `print` with a newline at the end.

Comment: Thanks, obviously correct. This happens when starting with perl after 6 month pause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of hashes to store the data as one unit. Do this where you populate `@x` and `@names`. (Assuming the x-value is in `$x` and the name is in `$name`.)

```
push @data, {
    name => $name,
    x    => $x,
};
```

To retrieve a name at index `$i`: `$data[$i]{name}`

To retrieve a x-value at index `$i`: `$data[$i]{x}`

To iterate over the array:

```
for my $item_ref ( @data ){
    my $name = $item_ref->{name};
    my $x    = $item_ref->{x};
    # do something
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks. Seems to be better code then mine. Won't change it now since the script is working fine but I will consider it next time.